# Charts js showing only when positives data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an issue with charts js bar.
Here's the options :

```
trendChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: dynamicLabels,
        datasets: [{
            label: label1,
            data: displayedDatas1,
            borderColor: colors,
            backgroundColor: colors,
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 2
        }]
    },
    options: {
        showDatapoints: true,
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + ' %';
                }
            }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        emptyOverlay: {                             // enabled by default
            fillStyle: 'rgba(105,105,105,0.4)',     // Change the color of the overlay to grey with a 40% alpha
            fontColor: 'rgba(47,47,47,1.0)',     // Change the text color to white
            fontStroke: 'rgba(47,47,47,0)',     // Change the text color to white
            fontSize: $(window).width() > 1007 ? 25 : 15,
            message: "Veuillez sélectionner vos activités et services, et choisissez une période",
            fontStrokeWidth: 0                      // Hide the stroke around the text                
        }
    }
});
```

And how I update the data :

```
trendChart.data.datasets[0] = {
    label: label1,
    data: displayedDatas1,
    borderColor: colors,
    backgroundColor: colors,
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2
};
trendChart.data.labels = dynamicLabels;
trendChart.update();
```

The issue is when I have only negative data, the bars are not shown but when there is at least one positive data they magically appear.

I already tried: scaleBeginAtZero and ticks in the options.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `scaleBeginAtZero: false` to your `options` object.

```
scaleBeginAtZero: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

The issue was the plugin: chartjs-plugin-empty-overlay.js.
When disabling it the negative values are showing.
Should have read the doc, it was only tested for the line chart.